# Can't change baudrate in SARA-N2 modem

Tags: at-command, nb-iot

I am using Ublox evaluation kit with SARA-N210. The factory set baudrate is 9600 and I am trying to change it to 115200 with `at+natspeed=115200`, but it immediately goes back to 9600.

I read through the manual, and it says that to store at+natspeed settings, one needs to do this:

> SARA-N2
>
> - The module must enter in any of the following mode:
>
> o Enable the Power Saving Mode (PSM) by means of the
>
> +CPSMS
>
> AT command
>
> o Reboot the module reboot by means of the
>
> +NRB
>
> AT command

But this doesn't help. What are the exact steps to store the new baud rate value into the NVM and make it persist?

Comment: What if you provide `at+natspeed=115200,30,1`?

Comment: Another question: when you write `it immediately goes back to 9600`... how much time later? 1 second? 1 minute?

Answer (score 0):

This knowledge pertains to the SARA-N300 but as this is the next gen modem it probably also holds for the N2.

It will never work, the modem is just incapable of working at higher speeds. I know this because of an interaction with UBlox support. I couldn't connect using their tool and they were like: "oh yeah, that one can't run at that speed".